# AttributeErrorの直し方

Tags: python, python3

以下のエラーはどう直せばよいのでしょうか。

```
C:\UsersDesktop>python PrepareChain.py sample.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PrepareChain.py", line 249, in <module>
    chain = PrepareChain(text)
  File "PrepareChain.py", line 33, in __init__
    text = text.decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

該当する行については

#### 33行目周辺

```
32 if isinstance(text, str):
33           text = text.decode("utf-8")
34        self.text = text
```

#### 249行目周辺

```
 243 f = open(param[1], encoding='utf-8')
 244   text = f.read()
 245   f.close()
 246
 247  # print (text)
 248
 249   chain = PrepareChain(text)
 250   triplet_freqs = chain.make_triplet_freqs()
 251   chain.save(triplet_freqs, True)
```

です。

Answer (score 2):

decodeメソッドはバイト列を変換する際に用いられるメソッドです。そのためstringオブジェクトにdecodeメソッドは用意されていません。
今回のエラーはそれを指摘しているものです。stringオブジェクトからバイト列への変換にはencodeメソッドを利用してください。

```
text = text.encode('utf-8')
```

しかし、ファイルオープンの時点でencodingを指定しているのでこの処理自体必要ないかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、python2で書かれたプログラムをpython3で実行しようとされているのだと思います（strのdecodeはpython3にはないので）。

動かしたいのは以下で紹介されているTextGeneratorでしょうか。
https://karaage.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2016/01/27/073000

であればこのページが参考になるとおもいます。
[https://qiita.com/betit0919/items/4fbba42de6df90bc7088#text-generatorの利用](https://qiita.com/betit0919/items/4fbba42de6df90bc7088#text-generator%E3%81%AE%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8)

上記リンク先では、`2to3`でpython2のコードをpython3に自動変換したあと、ご質問の箇所を手動で訂正しています。

問題の箇所だけでなく、前提条件を漏れなく書くと回答をもらいやすいと思いますよ。